# Can I have a windows group with all the administrator privileges without the Remote Desktop privilege?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

Currently, I am using an account in the administrators group on a machine to kill the processes and stop/start windows services remotely using a tool written in c# (wmi) but this is causing issues because being in the administrator group also allows users to log on to the target machine via Remote Desktop and I don't want that.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

If the user doesn't need to log in at all, you can add it to the `Deny log on locally` security policy setting (or `Deny Log on through Terminal Services`, if you want to allow console login).

This can be done either through group policy on a domain or local security policy (`secpol.msc`); the setting is in `Security Policies -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment`.